# Android Studio: Plugin with id 'com.android.feature' not found

Tags: java, android, gradle

I moved an android studio project onto another computer and I got this error when the gradle was syncing:

```
A problem occurred evaluating project ':base'.
> Plugin with id 'com.android.feature' not found.
```

Here is the code in build.gradle (:base)

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.feature'

configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy {
        force 'com.android.support:support-annotations:23.1.1'
    }
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    baseFeature true

    defaultConfig {
       minSdkVersion 26
       targetSdkVersion 28
       versionCode 1
       versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {

    //noinspection GradleCompatible
    api 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    api 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:2.0.4'

    application project(':app')
    feature project(':app')
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')



}
```

Here are the gradle versions:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The `com.android.feature` plugin has been deprecated for some time and was finally removed in 4.0.0 of the Android Gradle Plugin. See [here](https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/gradle-plugin#4-0-0-behavior) for more details.

So, it looks like you have 2 options.

1. Migrate your app to work with the newer app bundling, if that applies to you.
2. Downgrade to 3.6.0 of the Android Gradle Plugin.